# My availability group doesn't work correctly

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I recently created an "availability group" on sql server, I created my Listener, all is well the high availability group appears well in the roles of my cluster. However I encounter a small problem, the two replicas are not really synchronized [image]

, then when I open my dashboard I have the error message [image]/i.stack.imgur.com/Gf9wK.png . why it does not work ? I have already done everything but nothing done.

I use windows server 2012 R2 and SQL SERVER 2016 Enterprise.

Comment: The secondary database is not joined to AG, as per the message. Can you add the secondary node into the AG

Comment: no i can't , may be should i grant all connection ?  @Shanky

Comment: Can you let me know error you are getting when you are trying to add the secondary replica. You can add that in the question

Comment: Do you have Windows firewall enabled?  If yes, open port 5022 on bother servers, which is the default port used for database replication.

Comment: @Shanky the second node replica is already added on the AG group but it's about secondary database i think and it makes this error message "DATABASE "TEST2" is not in a recovering state which is required for a mirror database or secondary database. The remote database must be restored using WITH NORECOVERY (Microsoft SQL error 1464) .

Comment: @TonyHinkle my firewall is disabled and test "telnet PLSDBATEST3 5022" is ok which means the port 5022 is open .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm you have the correct permissions on the endpoint?

```
USE master;
GO
SELECT SUSER_NAME(principal_id) AS endpoint_owner
    ,NAME AS endpoint_name
FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints;
GO

-- change the endpoint owner
USE master;
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON ENDPOINT::Hadr_endpoint TO sa;
GO

-- grant connect
GRANT CONNECT
    ON ENDPOINT::Hadr_endpoint
    TO [yourdomain\username]; -- account used for the SQL Service
```